# Prism and Using Unity IoC in Prism

Tags: unity-container, prism

### I am a total newbie on Prism. I have been getting to understand a lot from questions on SO and from various Blogs. I am using latest build – V2

I want some explanations on things that may be pretty easy things for you guys but it’s just not getting into my brains (small one for that). 
Instead of doing it all right the first time , for which I have spent more than two weeks looking at various blogs, webcast …., I thought to start  a project and learn.  The amount of information on those hundreds of sites was overwhelming and difficult to digest.
Currently my project  is setup like this 
Shell  --  Menu Module- ViewModel - - ->   Menu Service -- -- > Menu Repository  --- Data

All are in different assembly

MyShell ---  MenuModule                 ---MyServices --  Myrepository

Shell  is required to reference modules ( thought I am sure I can add it using string) later on .

ViewModel has a reference to View - Can live with it for now

View Model requires to use menu service   and menu service uses repository

All are built with constructor injection. I have it working now  by having  module reference  MyService  and Myrepository projects and then registering types at module level.
But this does not feel good.  I don’t want to hard reference any projects.  If we are referencing  projects why use IoC. In MenuModule.cs ( which is in the root of module) I  can register views  with unity container
I think I am getting a feel that  the answer to this one may lie in the first question

1. Is Configuration file the answer/
   Should I use configuration file for
   true decoupling?
2. If (somehow) we can
   register types from code, should we
   register types at module level ( I
   don’t want to  have hard reference to projects)
3. I need to know the
   Interfaces in advance so do you
   recommend separate assembly for just
   Interfaces?

Bear with me if the questions sound real stupid 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a configuration file for true decoupling.  All you need is to register your types in your shell's bootstrapper.  I usually break up my projects and refs like this.

**Contract Assembly**
(Contains only a few simple types and interfaces)

Referenced by:

- Shell
- Modules

**Shell** 
(Contains concrete implementations of interfaces defined in Contract assembly)

Referenced by:

- No one

**Modules** 
(Declares dependencies on interfaces defined in Contracts assembly, for instance IMenuRegistry)

Referenced by:

- No one (I use a Directory Module to search for modules in a directory)

Here's a sample project I put together.  In this sample I reference the module from the shell for simplicity's sake, but you can remove that reference and use a directory module catalog to load the compiled module at runtime:
http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/376992/CAGMenus.zip

Hope this helps,
Anderson

Comment: @Anderson:Thanks for your reply.Another clarification required.. If Shell has all concrete implementations of Interfaces then all my classes will be instntiated when my application starts or is it that IoC will resolve the types only when requested (on demand)

Comment: They are instantiated on demand unless you specify a special lIfetime manager.

Comment: Is there a way I can say  _container.RegisterType(IMenuRepository,<Myassembly, myclass, VersionNo>)

Comment: You can.  You'd have to do a Type.GetType and pass a string.  However I think I know what you are getting at and I think it would be better for you if your MenuModule registered its implementation of IMenuRegistry in a normal way in Initialize and your other modules simply declared that they had a module dependency on "MenuModule".

Comment: More about the [ModuleDependency("MenuModule")] stuff is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458911.aspx

Comment: @Anderson. Thanks  A lot of things have got cleared from your comments

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track. Use the configuration file to register your types, and put the interfaces in a separate assembly.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. Have a look at my comment on registering type with qualified assembly names